# JL3 upgrade causing typeError with ILabShell

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, jupyter-lab

The `ILabShell` in the codesnippet requires throws a `typeError`, this happened while trying to upgrade to JL3. Using `ILabShell as any` solves it but a warning is still thrown. It also happens for `IMainMenu`, `ICommandPalette`, etc.

**ERROR**

```
"Type 'Token<ILabShell>' is not assignable to type 'Token<any>'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_tokenStructuralPropertyT'".
```

**Code Snippet**

```
import { ILabShell, JupyterFrontEnd, JupyterFrontEndPlugin } from  '@jupyterlab/application';
..
..
..
..
..
..
..
const ClustersPlugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
id: CLUSTERS_PLUGIN,
requires: [
 ISageMaker,
 IAppState,
 // TODO: [JL3] Fix type error
 ILabShell,
 ILogger,
 IGraphQL,
 ISageMakerComponentsLeftPanel,
 IComponentsPanel,
 IFeatureFlags,
]
```